# Summarise across, nrow doesn't return anything

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Why does below return output as `data frame with 0 columns and 1 row`, I have no idea what it means either.

The code ran is

```
iris %>% summarise(across(everything(),nrow))
```

Note that both of the below returns an output as expected

```
iris %>% summarise(across(everything(),length))
iris %>% summarise(across(everything(),mean))
```

Ideal Output received

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
     150         150          150         150     150
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nrow` is used on dataframes, `across` does not pass data as dataframe it passes it as vector on which `nrow` does not work. For example,

```
nrow(1:10)
#NULL
```

You can use functions like `length`, `NROW` which works on vector to use in `across`.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that `NROW` is a function there.  Wow!!

Comment: `as.data.frame(lapply(iris, nrow))` works as expected. How to interpret the error message: `x 'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [2]` for `iris %>% summarise(across(everything(),nrow))`?

Comment: `lapply(iris, nrow)` returns `NULL` for all the columns. Do you mean `data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows` is expected output for OP ? I think they are looking for reason why `nrow` does not work with `across` .